# по поводу искусственного интеллекта в array php

Tags: php

[PHP] Имеется массив

```
$array = [список1,список1,список1,список2,список2,список3,список3,список3,список3];
```

Нужно чтобы вывод в html был таким:

```
<td>список1</td>
<td>список1</td>
<td>список1</td>
<td>Это был вывод значения из массива: список1 </td>
<td>список2</td>
<td>список2</td>
<td>Это был вывод значения из массива: список2 </td>
<td>список3</td>
<td>список3</td>
<td>список3</td>
<td>список3</td>
<td>Это был вывод значения из массива: список3</td>
```

Comment: а как вы понимаете, что кончился один список и начался другой?

Comment: думаю что легче создать несколько массивов, чем искуственный интеллект

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов может быть несколько. Вот некоторые из них.

**Вариант 1**

```
   <?php
    $array = ["список1","список1","список1","список2","список2","список3","список3","список3","список3"];
    $current = $array[0];
    foreach($array as $row)
    {
        if($row==$current)
        {
            echo $row."<br>";
        }else
        {
            echo "Это был вывод значения из массива:".$current."<br>";
            echo $row."<br>";
            $current=$row;
        }
    }
    echo "Это был вывод значения из массива:".$current."<br>";
    ?>
```

**Вариант 2**

```
    function array_group_by($arr)
    {
        $result=array();
        foreach ($arr as $value ) {
            $result[$value][] = $value;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    $array = ["список1","список1","список1","список2","список2","список3","список3","список3","список3"];
    $group = array_group_by($array);

    foreach($group as $gr)
    {
        foreach($gr as $row)
        {
            echo $row."<br>";
        }
        echo "Это был вывод значения из массива:".$gr[0]."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я думал мне этого кода хватит для доделки своего кода но я ошибся помогите пож-та снова.
Дано: Имеются значения в единственном массиве $array
Нужен вывод в таком виде:
<td>Название1</td>
<td>Название2</td>
<td>Название3</td>
<td>Это был вывод значения из единственного массива: Название </td>
<td>список1</td>
<td>список2</td>
<td>Это был вывод значения из из единственного массива: список</td>
<td>Терм111</td>
<td>Терм222</td>
<td>Терм333</td>
<td>Терм444</td>
<td>Это был вывод значения из из единственного массива: Терм</td>

Comment: Если вам нужен еще ответ, обновите ваш вопрос. Если ваш новый вопрос сильно отличается от уже заданного, то лучше задайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Моего интеллекта не хватило, чтобы понять, что это и на самом деле одинаковые элементы массива. Тогда можно так сделать

```
$array = ["список1","список1","список1","список2","список2","список3","список3","список3","список3"];

$cnt = array_count_values($array);
$out = [];
foreach ($cnt as $k=>$v) {
    $out = array_merge($out, array_fill(0, $v, $k), 
         [ "Это был вывод значения из массива: $k" ]);
}    
echo implode('<br>', $out);
```